# Center of symplectic derivation Lie algebra

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, mapping-class-groups

Morita–Sakasai–Suzuki studied the graded Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}_{g,1}$ of *symplectic derivations*, as well as variations $\mathfrak{h}_{g,\ast}$ and $\mathfrak{h}_g$. This is the Lie algebra of those derivations of a free Lie algebra on $H := H_1(\Sigma_{g,1};\mathbb{Q})$ which annihilate the symplectic form $\sum_{i=1}^g [a_i,b_i] \in \Lambda^2(H)$. See for example [Symmetry of symplectic derivation Lie algebras of free Lie algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.3963) or [Structure of symplectic invariant Lie subalgebras of symplectic derivation Lie algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.3351) by Morita–Sakasai–Suzuki.

> Is anything known about the centers of $\mathfrak{h}_{g,1}$, $\mathfrak{h}_{g,*}$, and  $\mathfrak{h}_{g}$? Are they trivial?